# How can I make the template folder the root folder for flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'd like my folder structure for Flask to be

```
main_folder
    app.py (Flask script)
    index.html
```

instead of the usual

```
main_folder
    templates
        index.html
```

However, if I do `app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='\')` it fails to find any of my files (including `index.html`) and I don't know why.

How can I get `index.html` to be in the same folder as the Flask script and still have it run?

Comment: `'\'` is the root folder of the current drive.

Comment: @KlausD. are you saying that I should use `'.'`?